# setState depending if Object.hasOwnProperty

Tags: reactjs

Working with external API, on request I get either Object with error or Object with current and forecast.

1. Object {error}
2. Object {current,forecast}.

I want to setState depending on which Object I get. I'm trying this:

`setFetchWeather = data => {
  const newState = data.hasOwnProperty(data.error) ? {data:[], error:true,loading: false} : {data: data.forecast, error:false, loading:false}
   this.setState(newState);
 }`

then

`{this.state.error ? <span>Error</span> : <span>Not an Error</span>}`;

get an error like this:

`Cannot read property 'forecastday' of undefined`

What I'd like is when Object contains current and forecast get an message "Not an Error" and when Object contains error, get an messsage "Error".

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I see it helps to explain problem to yourself 
It must be data.hasOwnProperty("error").

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand about half of what you have said, but I assume you want the "hasOwnProperty" function to trigger a response.

[You are using the function incorrectly.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

```
if (data.hasOwnProperty("error")) {
  this.setState({ ... });
}
```

Notice the quotation marks around the key name.